# Export clustered column charts with epplus and set up data tables, and the data tables switch to row and column display?

Tags: c#-4.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQ8sy.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnqrC.png)
Export clustered column charts with epplus and set up data tables, and the data tables switch to row and column display? How to do it

```
           var bColumnData = GetColumnData(sheet2, 2, 3);
            var dColumnData = GetColumnData(sheet2, 4, 3);

            // 将行数据转换为列数据
            var transposedData = TransposeData(bColumnData, dColumnData);
            // 获取柱状图对象
            var chart = (ExcelChart)sheet3.Drawings.First();
            // 更新柱状图的图例项
            // 如果柱状图中没有任何系列，则添加新系列
            if (chart.Series.Count == 0)
            {
                // 添加新系列
                var categoryData = sheet2.Cells[$"B{startRow}:B{endRowB}"];
                var valueData = sheet2.Cells[$"D{startRow}:D{endRowD}"];
                var newSeries = chart.Series.Add(valueData, categoryData);
               
                //newSeries.Header = "Series1"; // 设置新系列的标题
                // 添加每对 B 列和 D 列数据作为一个系列到柱状图中
                for (int i = 0; i < bColumnData.Count; i++)
                {
                    var bItem = bColumnData[i].Trim(); // 去除字符串两端的空格
                    var dItem = dColumnData[i];

                    // 添加新系列到柱状图
                    newSeries.Series = dItem;
                    newSeries.XSeries = dItem;
                    newSeries.Header = bItem; // 使用 B 列的值作为系列标题
                }
            }
```